# jScrollPane Scrollbar height relative to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I have a resizable div which is using custom scrollbars of jScrollPane.

I want to have vertical scrollbar above the resize handle, is it possible to do so?

I tried changing `verticalTrackHeight` to be always 40 less and bar size reduces too, but when we scroll the scroller goes to the bottom.

Here is my code http://www.jsfiddle.net/WRMSn/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like some extra space is somehow being added below the scrollbar. You can use a [jspCap](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/caps.html) to get around this using some code like this:

```
.jspCapBottom {
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
}
```

I added that to your fiddle and it seems to work well:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/UnEqt/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `;` on `var pane = $("#container")`

It should be `var pane = $("#container");`